# wrapfig not wrapping as required

Tags: floats, wrapfigure

Why isn't the text wrapping correctly here?

**code:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,wrapfig,lipsum}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[66]
\begin{wrapfigure}[12]{r}{4.5cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill (-1.1,-1.1) rectangle (3.3, 3.3);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{wrapfigure}
\[\mathbf{u} = (u_1,0,0)=(u,0,0)=u\mathbf{i}\]

Nunc sed pede. Praesent vitae lectus. Praesent neque justo, vehicula.
\[\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u} = 0 \implies \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial 0}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial 0}{\partial z} = 0\]

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

**output:**

[image]

Comment: I don't know why, but adding an empty line with `\ ` before the first equation seems to solve this problem.

Comment: You should never start a paragraph with a display.

Comment: @egreg Can you explain why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting a paragraph with a display is a sure source for bad output, particularly in connection with `wrapfigure`.

I guess your aim is to start the picture insertion down the paragraph; this can only be done with some manual work (in the final revision stage, of course).

One can add `\nopar` (defined in the code below) at the end of a suitable line, visually determined in a previous LaTeX run, insert the `wrapfigure` code and resume the paragraph.

Recall that every display is assumed to be three lines long, as far as the first optional argument to `wrapfigure` is concerned.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,wrapfig,lipsum}

\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}

\newcommand{\nopar}{{\parfillskip=0pt \par}}

\begin{document}

Nunc sed pede. Praesent vitae lectus. Praesent neque justo, vehicula eget, interdum id, facilisis et, 
nibh. Phasellus at purus et libero lacinia dictum. Fusce aliquet. Nulla eu ante placerat leo semper 
dictum. Mauris metus. Curabitur\nopar

\begin{wrapfigure}[11]{r}{4.5cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill (-1.1,-1.1) rectangle (3.3, 3.3);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{wrapfigure}

\noindent
lobortis. Curabitur sollicitudin hendrerit nunc. Donec ultrices lacus id ipsum.
\[
\mathbf{u} = (u_1,0,0)=(u,0,0)=u\mathbf{i}
\]
Nunc sed pede. Praesent vitae lectus. Praesent neque justo, vehicula.
\[
\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u} = 0 \implies
  \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
  + \frac{\partial 0}{\partial y}
  + \frac{\partial 0}{\partial z} = 0
\]
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]